# Error with range_sensor_layer. move_base node dies when a sensor_msgs/Range is published

Tags: ros, navigation, sonar, ros-melodic, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am trying to setup a **range_sensor_layer** to use an **ultrasonic sensor on the navigation stack**. I am using move_base in a custom mobile robot. The robot uses a computer with Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS and ROS Melodic (1.14.3). I am using one RGB-D camera and an ultrasonic sensor.

First I launch the navigation **without publishing sensor_msgs/Range on its topic**. Then I can navigate without the ultrasonic data. **When I launch the node that publishes the Range data, the move_base node dies.**

Can anybody help me to configure correctly the range_sensor_layer?

Following are my configuration files:

global_costmap_params.yaml

```
global_costmap:
  global_frame: map
  robot_base_frame: base_footprint
  update_frequency: 0.5
  publish_frequency: 0.5
  static_map: true

  plugins: 
    - {name: static_layer,    type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}       
    - {name: inflation_layer, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}
```

local_costmap_param.yaml

```
local_costmap:
  global_frame: odom
  robot_base_frame: base_footprint
  update_frequency: 2.0
  publish_frequency: 2.0
  static_map: false
  rolling_window: true
  width: 4.0
  height: 4.0
  resolution: 0.025
  origin_x: -2.0      
  origin_y: -2.0      

  plugins:    
    - {name: obstacle_layer, type: "costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"}       
    - {name: sonar_layer,   type: "range_sensor_layer::RangeSensorLayer"}
    - {name: inflation_layer, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}
```

costmap_common_params.yaml

```
footprint: [[0.095,  -0.202], [-0.095,  -0.202], [-0.310, -0.165], [-0.310, 0.165], [-0.095, 0.202], [0.095, 0.202]]  
footprint_padding: 0.025            

#layer definitions
obstacle_layer:  
    obstacle_range: 3.5     
    raytrace_range: 4.0      

    observation_sources: point_cloud_sensor

    point_cloud_sensor: {
      sensor_frame: camera_link, 
      data_type: PointCloud2, 
      topic: openni_points, 
      expected_update_rate: 0.5, 
      marking: true, 
      clearing: true,
      min_obstacle_height: 0.0,
      max_obstacle_height: 2.0,                                                                            
      origin_z: 0.0,        
      z_resolution: 0.05,  
      z_voxels: 40,                  
      publish_voxel_map: true 
    }

sonar_layer:
      ns: /robot/sensor/
      topics: ['sonar_forward_left']                             

inflation_layer:
    inflation_radius: 1.20               
    cost_scaling_factor: 2.58                                                   

transform_tolerance: 1

controller_patience: 2.0

NavfnROS:
    allow_unknown: true

recovery_behaviors: [
    {name: conservative_clear, type: clear_costmap_recovery/ClearCostmapRecovery},
    {name: aggressive_clear, type: clear_costmap_recovery/ClearCostmapRecovery}
]

conservative_clear: 
    reset_distance: 3.00
aggressive_clear:
    reset_distance: 5.00
```

The navigation launch log (working good) without publishing on sensor_msgs/Range Topic:

```
...
[ INFO] [1560451022.672595882]: Using plugin "static_layer"
[ INFO] [1560451022.678838847]: Requesting the map...
[ INFO] [1560451022.881123086]: Resizing costmap to 279 X 208 at 0.050000 m/pix
[ INFO] [1560451022.981045216]: Received a 279 X 208 map at 0.050000 m/pix
[ INFO] [1560451022.983909307]: Using plugin "inflation_layer"
[ INFO] [1560451023.023428562]: Using plugin "obstacle_layer"
[ INFO] [1560451023.024910763]:     Subscribed to Topics: point_cloud_sensor
[ INFO] [1560451023.049016230]: Using plugin "sonar_layer"
[ INFO] [1560451023.051504866]: local_costmap/sonar_layer: ALL as input_sensor_type given
[ INFO] [1560451023.053644089]: RangeSensorLayer: subscribed to topic /robot/sensor/sonar_forward_left
[ INFO] [1560451023.065115576]: Using plugin "inflation_layer"
[ INFO] [1560451023.111015732]: Created local_planner base_local_planner/TrajectoryPlannerROS
[ INFO] [1560451023.126600417]: Sim period is set to 0.20
[ INFO] [1560451023.254282343]: Approximate time sync = true
[ERROR] [1560451023.620386435]: obstacles_detection: Parameter "min_cluster_size" has moved from rtabmap_ros to rtabmap library. Use parameter "Grid/MinClusterSize" instead. The value is still copied to new parameter name.
[ERROR] [1560451023.621727209]: obstacles_detection: Parameter "max_obstacles_height" has moved from rtabmap_ros to rtabmap library. Use parameter "Grid/MaxObstacleHeight" instead. The value is still copied to new parameter name.
[ WARN] [1560451025.131534696]: The openni_points observation buffer has not been updated for 2.10 seconds, and it should be updated every 0.50 seconds.
[ WARN] [1560451025.131593002]: The openni_points observation buffer has not been updated for 2.10 seconds, and it should be updated every 0.50 seconds.
[ WARN] [1560451025.131736352]: Illegal bounds change, was [tl: (-179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368.000000, -179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368.000000), br: (179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368.000000, 179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368.000000)], but is now [tl: (-340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000, -340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000), br: (340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000, 340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000)]. The offending layer is local_costmap/inflation_layer
[ INFO] [1560451025.203243618]: Recovery behavior will clear layer obstacles
[ INFO] [1560451025.236163764]: Recovery behavior will clear layer obstacles
[ INFO] [1560451025.266917270]: odom received!
[ WARN] [1560451109.575399918]: Messages of type 2 arrived out of order (will print only once)
[ WARN] [1560451109.576543482]: Messages of type 0 arrived out of order (will print only once)
```

Then, when I launch the node that publishes the ultrasonic sensor data on a sensor_msgs/Range Topic, the move_base dies on the same time.

Here is the log:

```
...
[ WARN] [1560451109.575399918]: Messages of type 2 arrived out of order (will print only once)
[ WARN] [1560451109.576543482]: Messages of type 0 arrived out of order (will print only once)
/opt/ros/melodic/lib/move_base/move_base: symbol lookup error: /opt/ros/melodic/lib//librange_sensor_layer.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3tf212getTimestampIN13geometry_msgs13PointStamped_ISaIvEEEEERKN3ros4TimeERKT_
[planner/move_base-1] process has died [pid 14104, exit code 127, cmd /opt/ros/melodic/lib/move_base/move_base openni_points:=/planner_cloud map:=/rtabmap/grid_map move_base_simple/goal:=/move_base_simple/goal cmd_vel:=/cmd_vel odom:=/rtabmap/odom __name:=move_base __log:=/home/nuc/.ros/log/22d3e9aa-8dfc-11e9-9c26-a11a53c44629/planner-move_base-1.log].
log file: /home/nuc/.ros/log/22d3e9aa-8dfc-11e9-9c26-a11a53c44629/planner-move_base-1*.log
```

**I could not find the log file of this error.**

The range sensor is working.

rostopic echo /robot/sensor/sonar_forward_left

```
...
header: 
  seq: 34
  stamp: 
    secs: 1560451337
    nsecs:  80173661
  frame_id: "sonar_forward_left"
radiation_type: 0
field_of_view: 0.457276314497
min_range: 0.0399999991059
max_range: 4.0
range: 1.55999994278
---
...
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/325716/error-with-range_sensor_layer.-move_base-node-dies-when-a-sensor_msgs/range-is-published/) by [VitorHirozawa](https://answers.ros.org/users/33360/vitorhirozawa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2019-06-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-13**:
I have no idea what is causing it, but those bounds look highly suspect to me. They look like uninitialised memory of `double`s, or perhaps even integers interpreted as doubles, or something else that's wrong there.

I would first fix that before suspecting the sonar messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Get the fresh version from github, it was fixed: https://github.com/DLu/navigation_layers/issues/46

---

Originally posted by [AlexM](https://answers.ros.org/users/41877/alexm/) with karma: 51 on 2019-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [VitorHirozawa](https://answers.ros.org/users/33360/vitorhirozawa/) on 2019-07-17**:
Thank you for your response @AlexM. I tried to use the code from github https://github.com/DLu/navigation_layers using git clone and it worked.